# Is 'bunch' meaning 'protuberance, swelling' used in British English?

Tags: meaning, british-english

Looking up 'bunch' with reference to a question on ELL, I noticed that Merriam-Webster's first definition is *protuberance, swelling.* I don't see a similar meaning given by other online dictionaries, so presumably it's an American usage.

Oddly, the only time I've ever seen the word used in that sense is in Patrick O'Brian's novels. Some of his characters use it to refer to a camel's hump(s).

> "Come, Doctor, as a natural philosopher you will certainly confirm that the dromedary is the hairy animal with two bunches that moves slow."

Has anyone else come across this in British English?

Comment: [Oliver Goldsmith](https://www.ancestry.co.uk/genealogy/records/oliver-goldsmith-24-5xsk99) Birth27 March 1841 - Waterman's Fields, Woolwich, ENGLAND, Death5 Dec 1922 - Gisborne, New Zealand, so I assme he wrote in "British English". Talking about a kind of hedgehog, he wrote [*...  resembling a small animal , **with a bunch on its back***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22small+animal+with+a+bunch+on+its+back%22) where it's contextually obvious that ***bunch*** is a ***protuberance, swelling***. But that's just the first one I found. I'm sure there will be others.

Comment: https://nationalhumanitiescenter.org/pds/becomingamer/growth/text8/florafauna.pdf (see p. 8)

Comment: Is having hair or fabric in a bunch not acceptable British usage? That seems to fit the usage of "a protuberance" better than "a group of similar items".

Comment: How often do most people discuss protuberances or swellings on the bodies of animals, or even talk about goitres? These days people tend to use medical terminology for pathological swellings (or at least more specific terms like stye) in the rare cases they mention them. What I'm saying is, how often is it used in US English, and is it more or less than in UK English?

Comment: I have not heard it used in that sense.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie - _Is having hair or fabric in a bunch not acceptable British usage?_  Certainly it is - but I count  that as the normal 'things gathered together' definition.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie I also consider that to be "things fastened together". You create it by "bunching up" the hair.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since it’s been around since c1325, I don’t think we can label it American English. From the *OED*:

> **bunch** *noun<sup>1</sup>*
> **1.a.** A protuberance, *esp.* on the body of an animal; a hump on the back (of a human being, a camel, etc.); a goitre; a swelling,
> tumour. **c1325–**
>  <sub>Source: [*Oxford English
> Dictionary*](https://www.oed.com/dictionary/bunch_n1?tab=meaning_and_use#12124921) (login required)</sub>

Comment: [Online Etymology Dictionary](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=bunch) has this meaning.

Comment: "Since it’s been around since c1325, I don’t think we can label it American English". Not true; it could go either way, since American English has a number of relics that have dropped out of usage in modern British English. You have to look at usage, not etymology.

Comment: "Now _rare_" is the usage label in the SOED (no precision as to a particular variety of the language).

Comment: " a hump on the back (of a human being..." .. I wonder if this was the result of a typo or other confusion with _hunch_ (like in hunchback)

Comment: Thank you, folks. It looks as though it is one of those 'old-fashioned' expressions that O'Brian used in his historical novels.

Comment: @Laurel I think the meaning was that we can’t label it a usage that arose in and is particular to US English. It may have fallen out of use elsewhere, but it is not a US _invention_.

Comment: @muru The etymonline entry for "hunch" suggests that it may be the other way around. This use of "bunch" is older.